# Filter ModelViewSet with Url Param

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to filter my `ModelViewSet` by providing a URL param. So, for example:

```
class WidgetViewSet(ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Widget.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WidgetSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Widget.objects.filter(id=id) # id would be a url param
```

Let's say I ping `/widgets/43`. This would filter `Widgets` with `id=43`. How can I do this?

Answer (score -2):

First of all, in the URL `/widgets/43`, 43 is not a URL param but part of the URL path.
The modelviewset already implements getting a specific object in that way. So, remove your `get_queryset()` method and try it and you will see that it works by default. Take note of the trailing slash and add it if the router needs it.
I will advice reading more about [DRF Viewsets](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) on the docs.

A URL param however, is of this type `/widgets?id=43`. Here, id is a URL param and you can retrieve it in the viewset in this way:
`self.kwargs['id']`
If you want to have many params and more complex filtering, consider using [django-filter's integration with DRF](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/rest_framework.html#adding-a-filterset-with-filterset-class)